# ionic4 ion-select placeholder opacity can't be change

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

Not able to change placeholder opacity in ionic v4

i have tried to change opacity of ion-select placeholder in 
global.css

following is my code

> .select-placeholder 
>     {
>             opacity: 1 ;
>           }

```
but that didn't works , even i tried all methods to change it's css like
```

> ```
> ion-select{
>         --placeholder-opacity: 1 !important;
>     }
>     ion-select{
>          --opacity: 1 !important;
>     }
>     ion-select{
>         opacity: 1 !important;
>     }
> ```

```
etc... but not works fine , event it color change very well using following code
```

> ```
>    ion-select{
>          color: var(--ion-color-secondary);
>     }
> ```

```
no change , it took default opacity <style> tag.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Edited

```
<ion-select class="contact-us-select" interface="alert" [interfaceOptions]="customPopoverOptions"
        placeholder="selection" cancelText="cancel" okText="done" (ionChange)="onSelectChangevalue($event)">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of Data" [value]="item.id">{{item?.title}}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
```

Comment: can you add your html ?

Answer (score 5):

```css
ion-select{
    --placeholder-opacity: 1 !important;
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that's a **bug** of Ionic 4 (still happening in Ionic 4.4 as you can see in these github issues: [17446](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17446), [17166](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17166#issuecomment-489708230) and [17248](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17248)).

Unfortunately, since you cannot access directly to the shadow DOM to change that value, there's no much we can do to fix the issue for now.

One of the users suggested using a label as a workaround ([here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17446#issuecomment-490649798)) or even modifying a file from the node modules folder ([here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17446#issuecomment-489343857)) but I guess a *better* workaround would be to **preselect the first value by default**. So for example if the options are `Phone`, `Email`, `Live Chat`, instead of showing the placeholder, you could preselect `Phone` by default until this bug is fixed in Ionic's core.

Answer (score 2):

global.scss

```
ion-select{
     opacity: 0.3 !important;
     color: var(--ion-color-secondary);
}
```

that should work fine for changing global scss, you only need `--` for changing scss variables defined in the component.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try this in css file:

```
.select-ios .select-placeholder{
      color: #000;
      font-size: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to this path:
`[YOUR_PROJECT_PATH]/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/esm`

Look for this files:

> ion-select_3-ios.entry.js
>
> ion-select_3-md.entry.js

open it, and find:

`.select-placeholder{color:currentColor;opacity:.33}`

change it to what you want

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will help you, I tried on text box's placeholder, it works. For text box placeholder my code work, but for selection box I am not sure but, according to your code I think the following code may help you. Also, Run Code Snippet in which I code it for text box's placeholder.

```
 select::placeholder {
   opacity:0.5;
 }
```

```css
input::placeholder {
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Input box">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with ionic 4, this was my solution and works perfect

CSS

```css
ion-select.industry-group:before{content:"Select industry"}

ion-select<your class>:before{
    content: "Select Industry"
    opacity: 1;
    color: #00000
}
```

no placeholder in html

```html
<ion-select class="industry-group"  [formControl]="industryGroupFormControl" ok-text="Ok" cancel-text="Cancel">
```